# Google Compute Engine - pricing in what currency?

Tags: google-compute-engine

When you're creating a new VM from Google Compute Engine, from top right of Google Console: "You have $12345 free trial credits remaining"
That looks in local currency (i.e. not USD)

I looked up and down cant find a confirmation of this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we're not customer support for Google](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: If you registered in Hong Kong for your Google Cloud Account, you are being charged in local currency - Hong Kong dollar. Hong Kong uses the `$` sign for currency. Go to the Console Billing section and look it up.

Comment: @john, i did look it up: their support came back to me: 1) under Billing section, charges in local CCy HKD for example, under 2) Create new VM instance - estimates are in USD. Also yes JJJ, I shud go Google Support - they came back very quickly, and no Policing censorship by dudes with too much time

Comment: @user3761555 Would you be able to post this comment as an answer for the benefit of the community.? This is in case another member faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) under Billing section, charges in local CCy HKD for example,

2) Create new VM instance - estimates are in USD